Validation error: Invalid request headers
I'm currently exploring Docker and facing an issue when running my Angular frontend and Node.js backend inside Docker containers. Everything works fine when I run both applications locally on my development machine. However, when I dockerize the apps and try to interact with the backend from the frontend, I get the following error in the browser console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
Validation error: Invalid request headers

Local Setup (Works Fine):
Running Angular with ng serve.
Running Node.js backend with npm start.
The frontend successfully communicates with the backend.
Docker Setup (Causing Issues):
Dockerized both the Angular frontend and Node.js backend.
Used Dockerfile to create and run the containers.
Created custom network and running the both containers on same network
Both containers are up and running, and I can access the frontend and backend individually.
Node Dockerfile
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

COPY . .

RUN npm ci --legacy-peer-deps

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]

Angular Dockerfile
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

COPY . .

RUN npm ci --legacy-peer-deps

EXPOSE 3100

CMD ["npm", "start"]

Commands used to run the docker container
docker run \
--name=frontend \
--network=custom-net \
--publish=host-ip:3100:3100 \
frontend

docker run \
--name=backend \
--network=custom-net \
--publish=host-ip:3000:3000 \
backend


What is the URL you're trying to connect to?  What is the exact error you're getting?  What does the Angular code that tries to make that connection look like?  Can you call the backend using curl from the host system?  The specific ports here are confusing; are the docker run -p options correct, and what ports have you configured the application to use (not Docker setup, but in your application code or config files)?

@DavidMaze I am trying to connect https://host-ip:3000 from https://host-ip:3100.  I am not able to call the bakend from host system. I had run the application on ip 0.0.0.0 and while running the image I am binding it to host-ip. In the docker run command I am providing the same ports which are in my config file

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What code, exactly, is making the call, and where is it running?  How are you coming up with host-ip?

@DavidMaze I had put the wrong ports in command, I edited it in the question

Do you have any CORS settings in backend?
